# perl count mismatch between two strings

Tags: string, perl, mismatch

I need to just count mismatch between two strings. Let say:

```
my $s1 = "ATCG";
my $s2 = "ATTG";
```

This should give: 1 as mismatch. No need to find position or what are the mismatches.

I was looking for fast way to do. I thought splitting into arrays and matching in loop or using substr to match each position may be slow because need to be checked for more than billion pairs. Thanks

Comment: Are the two inputs always the same length? If not, "ABCD" and "ACD" have a difference of 1, or something else? Even if so, do "ABCDEF" and "ACDEFB" have a difference of 2, 5, or something else?

Comment: If you are agree something a little more http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Levenshtein/lib/Text/Levenshtein.pm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just XOR the two strings together. Each NUL character in the result represents a position where the characters are the same in both strings.

```
my ($s1, $s2) = qw( ATCG ATTG );

my $count = ( $s1 ^ $s2 ) =~ tr/\0//c;

print "$count\n";   # Prints "1"
```

---

Note: If you're going to repeatedly compare a string, pass it and the one to which you are comparing it to `utf8::downgrade` to makes sure the `^` is as fast as it can be.

```
utf8::downgrade($s1);  # Change the internal format in which
utf8::downgrade($s2);  #   the strings are stored to speed up $s1^$s2.
```

This is useless/wasteful if either string contains UNICODE chars above U+00FF.

Comment: nice answer can you share use of `^` in your code and how it is works.?

Comment: XOR is a bitwise operator that finds difference between pairs of bits. So it becomes a question of counting the bytes with 1-bits, or the ones that don't consist entirely of zero bits.

Comment: Fantastic solution. I was looking concise like this one. Thanks

Comment: I phrased it so it'll be of use to others too

Comment: @ikegami: Will there be any problem with ATCG, I am using this one just for DNA?

Comment: The comparison will work fine for any characters. The downgrading will may help in the situation I describe. The downgrading may hurt in the situation I described. Unaccented latin letters are below U+0100.

Comment: @ikegami Is it possible to store the matched string to an array or other data type from your answer.? Like `@data = ($s1 ^ $s2) =~tr///;`

Comment: `push @matches, $s1 if ...;`